# Handle AJAX image upload with node and express

Tags: ajax, node.js, file-upload, canvas, express

I would like to upload an image to my node server using AJAX;

from the application I make the following:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas' + index);
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:9001/uploadimages",
    data: { 
        imgBase64: dataURL
    }
}).done(function(o) {
    console.log('all_saved'); 

});
```

And in the node server:

```
GMserver.post('/uploadimages', function(req, res) {
    var data_url = req.body.imgBase64;
    var matches = data_url.match(/^data:.+\/(.+);base64,(.*)$/);
    var ext = matches[1];
    var base64_data = matches[2];
    var buffer = new Buffer(base64_data, 'base64');

    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/images', buffer, function (err) {
        res.send('success');
        console.log('done');
    });
});

GMserver.listen(process.env.PORT || 9001);
```

Well, it takes something like 1.5 minutes to complete; and then, even if it says 'done' from node's console and 'all_saved' from browser's console, there isn't any file in the images directory;

anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you haven't provided a filename for the write. You're trying to save your file to `/whatever/images`, which is going to be a directory. it should be `/whatever/images/nameoffile.jpg`

Comment: I tried this:  fs.writeFile(__dirname + 'file1.jpg', buffer, function (err) {   but it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, you were right, i forgot a "/":    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/file1.jpg', buffer, function (err) {      this works, but is it normal that it takes so much time?

Comment: just how big of an image are you uploading? Probably the node stuff's running very quickly, but it's taking forever to actually do the upload.

Comment: Yes, the image is 1,5 MB... The original image is 2048 x 1536 of resolution (635 kB); i use the canvas to resize it client-side to 100 x 750 and after this the size is increased to 1,5 MB... Probably i'm doing something wrong in the resize process... Thanks for help